# How to change where clause dynamically in SOQL in salesforce node in Node Red

Tags: salesforce, node-red

How to take parameter from post API and use that in where clause in SOQL in node red.
In my case I am passing 'name' from postman and in node red have connected salseforce SOQL node with http(post) node. Trying to change where clause as where name = '{msg.payload.name}' but its not working.

How to do it ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are 10 different Salesforce nodes listed on flows, Please edit the question with the exact name of the node you are using so we can look to see what it actually supports.

Comment: I have mentioned here It's SOQL node

Comment: That doesn't help me work out which of the 10 different installable collection of nodes it is? e.g. node-red-contrib-salesforce or node-red-contrib-force

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I was not aware of that. I am using node-red-contrib-salesforce. Btw below answer worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is for the SOQL node in the node-red-contrib-salesforce collection of nodes.

The doc for this node explains that the query can be passed in via the `msg.query` parameter.

> The query can be configured in the node, however if left blank, the query should be set in an incoming message on msg.query. See the Salesforce SOQL documentation for more information.

So to do what you want you will have to build the query in a function node or a change node before passing it into the SOQL node.